# いろいろお世話になりました。->いいえ、こちらこそ。 or またいらっしゃってください。

Tags: honorifics

いろいろお世話になりました。

hello, in my book I found the 2 following replies to the above statement, which one is correct?
Are they both correct?
In what circumstances should each of these replies be replied to if they are both correct?

1 - いいえ、こちらこそ。
or
2 - またいらっしゃってください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which one is correct? Are they both correct?

Yes, both are correct.

---

> In what circumstances should each of these replies be replied to if they are both correct?

They're both typical formality quotes and makes not much difference. If I had to explain the difference, it would be:

**1 - いいえ、こちらこそ** if you want to be humble. "You owe me nothing".

**2 - またいらっしゃってください** if you want to emphasize hospitality. "Please come again".

You can combine them too - いいえ、こちらこそ。またいらっしゃってください would be good.

---

This may be a subjective question. If someone thanked you, would you emphasize "that was nothing to thank me for" or would you emphasize "sure, you're very welcome" ? Depends on the time, place, and occasion :)